# outgoing audio is heavily distorted

Tags: networking, 18.04, upgrade, sound

This has been driving me nuts for more than two months.

I recently upgraded Ubuntu from 16 to 18.04. Since the upgrade, my outgoing sound from a Logitech C270 usb microphone is heavily distorted on both Skype and Hangouts. At the other end, I sound like an unintelligible *duck*. This happens only to the outgoing sound: I have recorded myself locally, and there’s no distortion. The incoming sound is also ok, and sound from an analog microphone works fine.

The problem has something to do with some relationship between usb audio and network audio.

I have tried autoremoving, purging and reinstalling both pulseaudio and alsa, with no improvement. Could someone please help me?

Comment: Please issue the command `mv ~/.config/pulse ~/.config/old_pulse`. **Reboot** your system. Now, please check your audio. If it fails, then try this command `sudo alsa force-reload`.  Now again check for audio. Also please post the output of `pulseaudio --check -v` command.

Comment: The first command (`mv ~/.config/pulse ~/.config/old_pulse`) seems to have worked! Thanks a lot. This was driving me crazy.